# Can the Battle Master fighter's Precision Attack maneuver be used on a melee spell attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, fighter, combat-maneuver, battle-master

I've searched here and in various reference books but can't find the answer to this specific question.

The description of the [Battle Master fighter](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#BattleMaster)'s Precision Attack [maneuver](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#Maneuvers-214) (PHB, p. 74) states that it can be used for any weapon attack.

Thorn Whip, for example, uses magic to create a weapon... that is not magic.
So would that "weapon" attack count towards as being able to used with Precision Attack, even though the attack is using a spell?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### No, it can't be used on a spell attack

Attacks are broken down into [weapon attacks](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#AttackRolls) and [spell attacks](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#AttackRolls).

Each of these can be either a melee attack or a ranged attack. So any attack must be one of the following:

- Melee Weapon Attack
- Ranged Weapon Attack
- Melee Spell Attack
- Ranged Spell Attack

Except for a few rare cases, if you're casting a spell that gives you an attack (like in the case of [*thorn whip*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/thorn-whip)), you'll be making one of the latter-most two. Some non-spell abilities grant spell attacks, too.

In every case, the spell or ability will tell you which of the options above you're making. In the case of [*thorn whip*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/thorn-whip), the relevant part of the spell description says:

> Make a melee spell attack against the target.

So this means you're making a spell attack with *thorn whip*, not a weapon attack.

The [Battle Master fighter](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#BattleMaster)'s Precision Attack [maneuver](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#Maneuvers-214) states (PHB, p. 74):

> When you make a weapon attack roll against a creature, [...]

This means that it only works with attacks of the first two kinds, where the character is making a conventional attack with a some sort of weapon held in hand(s). Notably, it can be a melee or ranged attack (Precision Attack doesn't care which); it only matters that it's a weapon attack, and not a spell attack.

Because *thorn whip* involves the character making a spell attack, that character can't use Precision Attack on that attack.

By way of example, there are spells that *would* benefit from the Battle Master fighter's Precision Attack such as Booming Blade or Green Flame Blade because they involve a making melee weapon attack.

Comment: Minor note - nothing in the *thorn whip* spell says the thorns spring from the ground; it just says "You create a long, vine-like whip covered in thorns [...]".

Comment: @v2 That was how I interpreted "lashes out at your command" since, if it was wielded like an actual whip, the caster wouldn't need to *command* it to lash out, merely attack with it. I'll edit the answer to remove that bit since it's not integral to the larger thesis.

Comment: It may be worth noting an example of a spell that *can* benefit from Precision Attack, such as Booming Blade. It specifically says "make a melee attack with a weapon".

Comment: @Glen. Good idea! I've added that, thanks!